# Server-to-server calls with YouTube API

Tags: authentication, oauth, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-ruby-client

I need to access the YouTube API, authenticating as a single account so I can access its videos, tags, comments, etc.

A `Public API Access` key does not seem to cover this scenario as tags aren't visible to the public. Is it necessary to implement OAuth just to authenticate one account? I have no intention of having other users authenticate with the web app - only the YouTube account that belongs to the owner of the web app.

I have the username & password for the YouTube account. Is there no way to authenticate one YouTube account with the API as a single-user?

A Service Account seems most suitable for me, but apparently the `v3` API doesn't support them.

Comment: There is no way to do what you're hoping; the YouTube API is only accessible via oAuth2 or a public access key. I suppose if you have the username and password, you could manually make the HTTP calls to get a refresh token, and then use that in your app to continually get access tokens when you need ... but that's a pretty brittle solution (and certainly not scalable). But unfortunately, that's how the API has been architected.

Comment: Thanks, that's as I had expected really. Not a problem as I think I can make do with the public API.